# jQuery Datatables - No matching records found

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable with server side pagination. I have modified my REST APIs to return the necessary data as specified in datatable documentation. The problem is the data like number of pages, total rows are seen in UI, but the rows are not seen. I'm getting a message as 'No matching records found', but the page count and total rows are seen in the datatable UI. I also checked the network tab for the API response and the data is in correct format as below:

```
{"recordsFiltered":34096,"data":[{"isCompleted":"true","stockNumber":0,"transactionCount":0},{"isCompleted":"false","stockNumber":1,"transactionCount":0},{"isCompleted":"false","stockNumber":2,"transactionCount":0},{"isCompleted":"false","stockNumber":3,"transactionCount":0},{"isCompleted":"false","stockNumber":4,"transactionCount":0},{"isCompleted":"false","stockNumber":5,"transactionCount":0},{"isCompleted":"false","stockNumber":6,"transactionCount":0},{"isCompleted":"false","stockNumber":7,"transactionCount":0},{"isCompleted":"false","stockNumber":8,"transactionCount":0},{"isCompleted":"false","stockNumber":9,"transactionCount":0}],"draw":1,"recordsTotal":34096}
```

Javascript code:

```
$('#stocklist').DataTable({
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {"url":"/fetchStocks,
                        "dataSrc": function(data){
                            return data;
                         }
                }
            });
```

Whenever I click the next page icon, the server returns the correct updated data and the datatable is also updated with latest row count and page count. But, the rows are not getting rendered and no errors are seen in browser console too. How to debug this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try following this example? https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Comment: Did you try sending response data in the form of multi-dimensional array as shared shown in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `dataSrc` option as a function, you need to make a modification:

```
"ajax": {
  "url":"/fetchStocks",
  "dataSrc": function(data){
    return data.data;
  }
}
```

(*Please note: there is a missing closing `"` for the URL string, in the example in your question. That is a syntax error, so I assume it's a copy/paste issue of some kind.*)

I changed your `return data` to `return data.data`.

The reason for this is: When you assign your JSON response to a parameter in the function, you end up with a slightly different-shaped JSON response:

```
{
    "recordsFiltered": 34096,
    "data": {
        "data": [{
            "isCompleted": "true",
            "stockNumber": 0,
            "transactionCount": 0
        }, {
            "isCompleted": "false",
            "stockNumber": 1,
            "transactionCount": 0
        }, 
...
        }, {
            "isCompleted": "false",
            "stockNumber": 9,
            "transactionCount": 0
        }]
    },
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 34096
}
```

Now, in order to find the array where your table data starts, you therefore have to use `data.data`.

Just for clarity: If your function's parameter name had been `foo`, then you would have needed this:

```
"ajax": {
  "url":"/fetchStocks",
  "dataSrc": function( foo ){
    return foo.data;
  }
}
```

---

Having said that, there is no need to use `dataSrc` here, since you are not manipulating the JSON in any way (apart from assigning it to a new variable).

By default, DataTables expects to find the table's array data in a top-level object called `data` - which it already is, in your original JSON:

```
{ "recordsFiltered":34096, "data": [{"isCompleted":"true", ...
```